# Use Vitepress components in my Vue.js application

Tags: vue.js, components, vitepress

I'm **not** building a documentation website, I'd just like to take advantage of Vitepress components to build my own regular Vue.js application.

I installed Vitepress `npm i -D vitepress`, imported `vars`, `base`, `fonts` stylesheets from the `/node_modules/vitepress/dist/client/theme-default/styles` directory, then included the Layout component like so:

```
<script setup>
import Layout from "vitepress/dist/client/theme-default/Layout.vue"
</script>

<template>
    <Layout>
        <div>Hello world</div>
    </Layout>
</template>
```

I get a weird error in the browser console: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier '__vite__injectQuery' has already been declared (at ${mod.id}:52039:1)`

The same with any other Vitepress component (such as `VPButton` or `VPFooter`). I don't have any Vitepress specific configuration since I won't be using the vitepress CLI.

Is there any easy way to include Vitepress components "as-they-are" in a regular Vue.js application?